# Vendor's employee joining the contracting company

Tags: recruitment

I once worked at a small company that was a vendor for a big company.
My supervisor knew that the contract with the vendor would be ending some time that year but she proceeded to hire me without telling me of such.  I would not have joined had I known.

Unlike her predecessor, she was known to bend over backwards to every request of that big company no matter how unreasonable it was to the company that hired her.

After a few months she resigned and I came to know that she got a job with the big company.

I eventually deduced that she was so accommodating to those requests because she didn't want to burn bridges.  Somehow it worked out for her.

However, is it right of her to do so and is it right for the big company to hire her?

Since her previous company was the one who paid her salary, isn't she obligated to work in a way that benefited the company instead of herself?

Also, shouldn't hiring managers be wary of hiring anyone who is from a vendor company? This is because such people (not all, obviously) have proven that they will put their self-interest ahead of the company.  Such people are no different than traitors.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Retrenched. They lost the contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- No it is not unusual
- It is not disloyal, as long as she did not act against the interest of her employer (beyond quitting)
- It is absolutely normal that a hiring manager would not tell an applicant everything
- For sure her experience in the area and the client company are what is interesting to the client company.
- Usually suppliers and client companies have agreements for such situations.